# php site not ending with .php instead of ending with just the filename only thus giving a 404 error

Tags: php

I am having an issue for past 3 days, my site isn't ending its pages with .php which is giving 404 error everytime.

Say clicking on home should redirect to /home.php but instead its redirecting to website.com/home although before it used to work while going to /website.com/home but now I am getting a 404 error and I need to manually type .php at the end of the page to make it work.

say I want to visit home, I need to do website.com/home.php or I want to visit post I need to do website.com/post.php

I think there is a way to force all /home /post etc to .php but I am unaware of that. I can see the same happen with wordpress where the .php is not required so I just want to know how to do it.

Maybe via htaccess or something?

So I know if I modify this on the bellow code which is from /home.php I will get .home.php when I click but  I don't want to manually change each and every page now, and want all the /home /login /logout /admin /post page to redirect to .php

```
            <div class="header-buttons">
                <a class="header-button" href="home.php">
                    <button>home</button>
```

Here is the home.php code for example, is there a way to redirect href="home" to home.php directly without editing all the php pages and changing the href..

```
<?php 
session_start();

require 'configuration/config.php';
require 'configuration/functions.php';

if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test <?php sitename(); ?></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/home.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <p class="another-title-top header-title"><?php sitename(); ?></p>
            <div class="header-buttons">
                <a class="header-button" href="home">
                    <button>home</button>
                </a>
                <a class="header-button" href="posts">
                    <button>posts</button>
                </a>
                <a class="header-button" href="premium">
                    <button>premium posts</button>
                </a>
                <a class="header-button" href="create">
                    <button>Create Post</button>
                </a>
                <a class="header-button" href="shop">
                    <button>Store</button>
                </a>
                <a class="header-button" href="tos">
                    <button>ToS</button>
                </a>
                <?php 
                $sql = "SELECT role FROM users WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['user']."'";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
                    $adminbtn = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                    $admin_button = $adminbtn['role'];

                    if($admin_button == "admin"){
                        echo '<a class="header-button" href="admin/index"><button>Admin</button></a>';
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="top-header">
                <a href="profile">
                    <img src="assets/img/profile/undraw_pic_profile_re_7g2h.svg" alt="" class="profile-picture">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="totalgraph">
                <p class="total-users another-title">Total Users:</p>
                <p class="users-count another-title-top"><?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM users"; $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                    echo mysqli_num_rows($result);
                }else{
                    echo "0";
                }?></p>
            </div>
            <div class="totalgraph">
                <p class="total-users another-title">Total Posts:</p>
                <p class="users-count another-title-top"><?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts"; $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                    echo mysqli_num_rows($result);
                }else{
                    echo "0";
                }?></p>
            </div>
            <div class="totalgraph">
                <p class="total-users another-title">Total Premium Posts:</p>
                <p class="users-count another-title-top"><?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE premium = '1'"; $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                    echo mysqli_num_rows($result);
                }else{
                    echo "0";
                }?></p>
            </div>
            <div class="totalgraph">
                <p class="total-users another-title">Your Posts:</p>
                <p class="users-count another-title-top"><?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE `posted-user` = '".$_SESSION['user']."'"; $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                    echo mysqli_num_rows($result);
                }else{
                    echo "0";
                }?></p>
            </div>

            <div class="news">
                <p class="another-title" style="position:absolute; transform:translate(-50%, -50%); left:50%; top:0.5%; font-size:23px;">News:</h1>
                <?php 
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                    while($newsinfo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){?>
                <div class="news-table">
                    <p class="news-title another-title-top"><?php echo $newsinfo['news-name']; ?></p>
                    <p class="description-title another-title"><?php echo $newsinfo['news-description']; ?></p>
                </div>
                <?php
                    }
                }else{
                    echo '<h1 class="another-title" style="position:relative; top:50px;">No News!</h1>';
                }
                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="profile">
                <img src="assets/img/profile/undraw_male_avatar_re_nyu5.svg" alt="" class="profile-pfp">
                <p class="profile-info another-title-top"><?php echo $_SESSION['user']; ?></p>
                <p class="profile-info another-title"><?php $sql = "SELECT role FROM users WHERE username='".$_SESSION['user']."'";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                    while($userinfo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                        echo "Role: ".$userinfo['role'];"";
                    }
                } ?></p>
                <p class="profile-info another-title-top"><?php $sql = "SELECT status FROM users WHERE username='".$_SESSION['user']."'";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                    while($userinfo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                        echo "Status: ".$userinfo['status'];"";
                    }
                } ?></p>
                <a href="shop">
                    <button class="profile-shop">Shop</button>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<?php 
}else{
    header("Location: login");
}
?>
```

Comment: If this worked for you so far, without having explicitly implemented anything in that regard - then you have likely been relying on your web server's content negotiation feature / MultiViews. This makes the webserver look for files that are named "similar" to the one actually requested, but that will not always work as you want it to. Implement an explicit solution, like explained in the duplicate.